# Change a boolean value on home button click in Android

Tags: android, button

I'm trying to change a boolean value only on home button press. Can anyone tell me a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at  [onUserLeaveHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29) :

> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about to
>   go into the background as the result of user choice. For example, when
>   the user presses the Home key, onUserLeaveHint() will be called, but
>   when an incoming phone call causes the in-call Activity to be
>   automatically brought to the foreground, onUserLeaveHint() will not be
>   called on the activity being interrupted. In cases when it is invoked,
>   this method is called right before the activity's onPause() callback.

make Boolean variable true inside `onUserLeaveHint()` as:

```
 @Override
    public void onUserLeaveHint() {
                super.onUserLeaveHint();
                //make Boolean true here because this method first  
                //called when user press home key
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override Attached to window method.
Please check the following code.

```
 @Override
 public void onAttachedToWindow() {
 this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
 super.onAttachedToWindow();
 //set your boolean value here
 }
```